# Do I compute sample_weights on the original dataset or the training data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have an imbalanced dataset which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqfcF.png). I will use the a reweighing technique to improve the fairness of my dataset (a good example of this is shown in [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/reweighing-the-adult-dataset-to-make-it-discrimination-free-44668c9379e8) article).

Computing the weights is pretty straight forward, but my question is:

Do I compute these weights on the original dataset? Or do I compute the weights on the training dataset after I have performed an 80:20 split?

Comment: You should be computing the sample weights on the training data as while the model is training more weightage will be given to the data values with lesser data points.

Comment: That said, a useful rule of thumb is that first you split, and then, for all your modeling pipeline, you pretend as if you didn't have access *at all* to the test split.